# $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}Hom_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(I , \mathbb{C}[x,y]/ I)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Given an ideal $I \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I = n$, can the dimension of the space $Hom_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(I , \mathbb{C}[x,y]/ I)$ be determined in some elementary way?

$\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}Hom_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(I , \mathbb{C}[x,y]/ I)$

Comment: I doubt whether there is any easy way to calculate it.